# Why my code is only taking input but not returning any output?

Tags: c++

In this code, user will input multiple lines(string) and then those lines will be printed as output.The input will be terminated by EOF. Here in my code, this is only taking input but not returning any output. What is wrong in this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = "";

    int i=0;
    while (true) {
        char str = getchar();
        if (str!=EOF ||str!='\n') {
            i++;
            s = s+str;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout<<s;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Sample Input:

- The current platform was developed in 2005.
- It uses a very old version of Joomla, which makes maintenance a very difficult task.
- The way people uses internet services has changed a lot in 15 years.
- The new platform MUST be Open Source.

Sample Output:

- The current platform was developed in 2005.
- It uses a very old version of Joomla, which makes maintenance a very difficult task.
- The way people uses internet services has changed a lot in 15 years.
- The new platform MUST be Open Source.
```

Comment: the simple fix to your code is `if (str!=EOF)` (just remove `||str!='\n'`, but you have a better an more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str != EOF || str != '\n'
```

Short of some weird quantum mechanical realm, this `str` variable cannot be both `EOF` ***and*** `'\n'` at the same time :-)

- For a `str` value of `EOF`, this will give you `false or true`, which is `true`.
- For a `str` value of `\n`, this will give you `true or false`, which is `true`.
- For a `str` value of anything else, this will give you `true or true`, which is `true`.

In other words, it will *never* break out of that loop. You need instead:

```
str != EOF && str != '\n'
```

In any case, even with that fix, it will stop all processing on the first newline character which I don't think is what you want. You probably should just check for `EOF` and get rid of the newline check, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "";

    while (true) {
        int str = getchar();
        if (str == EOF) break;
        s += static_cast<char>(str);
    }

    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Also noticed that I've used the `int` type for the return value from `getchar()` - this is standard practice since it needs to be able to return every possible character *plus* an end-of-file indication.

---

You may also want to totally rethink your use of the legacy `cstdio` functions, C++ has a perfectly good [`getline` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) that can give you a whole line as a string. Something like this would be a good starting point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str;

    do {
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    } while (! std::cin.eof());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or even simpler (at least for me) `if (str == EOF || str == '\n') break;`

Comment: But It's just returning the first line, I need all the lines  :( @paxdiablo

Comment: You will need two loops. Break out of outer loop if EOF and break out of inner loop if '\n'.

Comment: the `EOF` check should be performed on the integer result of `getchar` rather than on a `char` value